# Modbus TCP to JavaScript Conversion

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, modbus

I'm wondering if the Modbus TCP protocol already being exported or converted to a JavaScript or a Plugging of some kind so a webpage can be created inside an HTML editor like Dreamweaver that can access this script and use it for controlling machine's PLC Inputs and Outputs and to manipulate and receive Temperature and Pressure data from analog sensors.

Does anyone knows if perhaps a type of gateway has already being written in Java that will interact between the Modbus-TCP protocol inside the PLC and an HTML page?

I'm a PLC programmer and a Dreamweaver user who is interested in developing a webpage for an Android tablet or a smart phones and be able to locally, via Wi-Fi, view and control our machines.

I know I can always use a dedicated TouchScreen but I'm looking to gain more control for the page HMI design.

Thanks for your help

Telemetrika

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527392/modbus-tcp-communication-from-html-javascript-webpage?noredirect=1#comment70295344_33527392

Answer (score 1):

[jsModbus](https://github.com/StevePo/jsModbus) is a Javascript client library for Modbus TCP