# Modbus TCP communication from HTML/Javascript Webpage

Tags: javascript, tcp, websocket, modbus

I have a device that uses Modbus TCP.  I want to read data from it and display it on a webpage (Without an in between server).

I have found a project that does almost this exact same thing as a Chrome extension:

https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/chrome-modbus

It uses this in the javascript code: chrome.sockets.tcp

I was hoping that I could do the same thing on my webpage using WebSockets.

It seems that websockets would work on my webpage (acting as the client), sending and receiving information from the device (acting as the server).  It doesn't seem that websockets is affected by cors.

Does anybody have pointers on where I could start on this? (Or a javascript library would be great)

Is this possible?

Comment: Several plc manufacturers have hardware or software available that will translate their protocols into standard tcp traffic you can access. (eg, the plcs we use have an optional hardware web module that speaks asp and hence, is ajaxable) It's possible to write custom connectors in node.js, but it's rather complicated coming from a webdev background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am really looking for a solution that would not involve any hardware or servers.  I don't see why this would be much different of concept from an HTTP request.  Using websockets I would think I could formulate the tcp packet in the way the device would understand and then send a modbus tcp command back.

Comment: @dgProgrammer Would you mind elaborating your solution into an answer? I am facing a similar problem and would like to know about your experience. Did you use a certain library? Or it is a direct modbus protocol implementation over web-sockets? Is your code available as open-source? Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: @jrierab

I used the following JS library [link](https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/chrome-modbus/blob/master/dist/modbus.js)
I followed the examples shown in the Readme.  They worked for me in my cordova app.  I had to include the library cz.blocshop.socketsforcordova.  
Are you trying to set this up in a web browser or cordova phone app?

Comment: @dgProgrammer I'm trying to use this in a [Ionic 2](https://ionicframework.com/) app, which uses Cordova in the build process. So, your solution looks promising. I will look into it and comment the results. Many thanks !

Comment: @dgProgrammer It is working on Android! I'm using your suggested [chrome-modbus library](https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/chrome-modbus) with the `cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp` plugin. Many, many thanks. You should also consider writing an answer to your own question and accept it, so other people reaching here will be pointed in the correct direction without needing to dig into comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get this solved without a server in between. I did it using Chrome Sockets [link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp) I also made it work using a cordova app for smart phones. Firefox has a sockets api as well, but did not attempt to figure it out for that browser.

Answer (score 3):

Without an in between server will not be possible, unless your plc supports other protocol different than modbus (e.g. post/get).

If your plc is "completely closed" and you only have this port/protocol open, then you need an in between server that makes the conversion of modbus tcp to html. Using node-red as well as the dashboard and modbus flows, you can achieve it.

If you solved it other way, I would like to know how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using the PLC Connect in vb, i used vb to pass data in database and get the data through javascript.